# [LibComponent -> BsModalService]

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I run into a simple... but ennoying issue with ModalModule:

I am using:
https://github.com/tinesoft/generator-ngx-library
to share components between projects.

here:

1) yeoman the lib

2) in the lib import ngx-bootstrap

3) write some code on the existing component ‘LibComponent’. Actually, i copy/pasted the exemple code of modals on ngxboot website.

4) gulp build

5) Try to execute the already defined demo in the library. (inside demo folder).

I have this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LibComponent -> BsModalService]:

Thx you in advance for any advice... I'm a bit lost :D.

I did all normal stuff like:

here is the code of the Lib Module:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ButtonsModule.forRoot()
      ],
      exports: [LibComponent],
      declarations: [LibComponent]
    })
    export class LibModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: LibModule,
          providers: [LibService]
        };
      }
    }
```

here is the code of the component:

```
      import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
      import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
      import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

      @Component({
        selector: 'zca-component',
        templateUrl: './lib.component.html'
      })
      export class LibComponent {
        modalRef: BsModalRef;
        constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

        openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
        }
      }
```

Comment: So ngx-bootstrap source code is included in resulting bundle, so you get duplicated `BsModalService` declaration in App

So question is: how is exclude ngx-bootstrap source code, from your libs bundle

Comment: Valorkin show me this solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr. It seems to be clearer and way easier.

Comment: Add this comment as an answer please, and mark this question as answered :)